# Form refreshes after clicking Submit

Tags: html, input, submit, forms

Both of these methods successfully send the data, but refresh the form (I'm trying to keep it hidden via jquery after clicking submit)

```
#1)  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>

#2)  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Based on other solutions,  I tried these 2 approaches. While they don't refresh the form, they don't send the data either.

```
#3)  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;">SUBMIT</button>

#4)  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

---

Entire code:

```
<?
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    include_once 'form.php';
    $message = 'Thank You';
    }
?>
----------- 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'other_radio') {
                $('#other').show();
            } else {
                $('#other').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

-----------
<div class ="form-hide">
<form method="post" role="form" id="survey">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="howdidyouhearaboutus" value="Facebook">Facebook</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="howdidyouhearaboutus" value="Online Ad">Online Ad</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="howdidyouhearaboutus" value="TripAdvisor">TripAdvisor</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;">
</div>
</form>

    <? if ($message): ?>
    <div class="text-center alert alert-success">
        <?= $message ?>
    </div>

<? endif; ?>

</div>
--------------------
<script>
 $('#submit').click(function(){
   $('.form-hide').hide();
 });
</script>
```

And form.php is for Google Sheets API integration, not sure if I need to include that here?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
try {
    $client->setAuthConfig('account.json');
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    exit('account.json not found.');
}
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https:    //spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']); ........
```

Comment: May I ask how you send your data? is it through Ajax or just via PHP?

Comment: #3 has a `return false;` which essentially means "do nothing". What does your form do? Please post the entirety of the code.

Comment: try after change input type="button" instead of submit. this may help

Comment: @sagivasan do you mean change it to:  <input type="button" value="Submit"> ? If so, that didn't send the data either.

Comment: @jake call function in onclick manually what submit do . submit will refresh page. if you want to stop refresh you need to use type button

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a form with an ID.
2. Create a script and then access that form through that given ID in the form tag.

   ```
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
   }
   </script>
   ```